# $wpdb->insert inserts only 19/20 rows

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a script that will insert a batch of rows (i.e. 40 rows) so I have an array with elements that will be saved in the database.

However, when I try to insert the rows, no matter what I do, it only inserts 19/20 rows,then it stops. I have tried the same thing with replace, and the same behavior appears.

Are there any settings I need to change or why does $wpdb insert only 20 rows?

Comment: please show some code

Comment: Yea show the data you are working on, at least which table are you inserting data to.